# Possible to extract locked archives?

Tags: archive, extract, unlock

I would like to bypass the lock on a .rar archive, is this possible?

Comment: All things are possible.  But "how to crack security on a file" is probably pretty badly off-topic for AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## AES is impractical to break.

This is impossible by definition. RAR uses pretty good cryptography, in fact 128-bit AES, which has insofar never been cracked via cryptanalysis or brute-force. You may want to try to find another format of the same archive with no security or one that is trivial to break, since this one will not be breakable.